# Can't map over array in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm passing an array (data) to the Segment component via a prop. But then I can't map over data. I'm sure it's a really obvious mistake but I just don't see it :(

```
import React from 'react';
import SegmentLine from './SegmentLine';

const Segment = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data);

  return data && data.map((line, i) => <SegmentLine key={i} data={line} />);
};

export default Segment;
```

The console.log is this:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: remove `{}` around map, also it seems like your data from some api calls, so you need to make your code to wait till the data arrives then only you can perform map

Comment: @CodeManiac Thank you so much!!! I can't believe this was the mistake... Did I mention I have worked with react for a few months already :'D

Comment: The waiting is fixed through the `data &&` I think

Comment: No problem sometime all it needs is other person eyes :)  No && doesn't fix waiting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think you have extra curly braces before the export.

Second, you should remove the curly braces between `data.map`.

```
return (
  data &&
  data.map((line, i) => {
    return <SegmentLine key={i} data={line} />
  })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either add a little improvement doing

```
return (
  data &&
  data.map((line, i) => (
    <SegmentLine key={i} data={line} />
  ));
```